# Orientation of $3$-tuples of $\mathbb{P}_K^1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, algebraic-groups

Let $K$ be a field, and let $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{P}_K^1$ be arbitrary distinct points. Then since the action of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(K)$ on $\mathbb{P}_K^1$ is simply $3$-transitive, there is a unique $g\in\mathrm{PGL}_2(K)$ such that $g(0)=a,g(1)=b,g(\infty)=c$. There is a well-defined map $\det\colon\mathrm{PGL}_2(K)\to K^\times/(K^\times)^2$, so to any $3$-tuple $(a,b,c)$ of points of $\mathbb P_K^1$, one can associate an element $\det(g)$ of $K^\times/(K^\times)^2$.

In particular, when $K=\mathbb F_q$ with $q\equiv1\pmod 4$, we have defined an "orientation" of any $3$-element subset $\{a,b,c\}\subset\mathbb{PF}_q^1$, as an element of $\mathbb F_q^\times/(\mathbb F_q^\times)^2\cong C_2$. Indeed, swapping the elements $a,b,c$ corresponds to composing $g$ with one of:
$$\{I_2,\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&\\1&-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}&1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\},$$
which all have determinant $\pm1\in(\mathbb F_q^\times)^2$. Thus, the orientation of $\{a,b,c\}$ is well-defined.

> Is there a nice interpretation of the "orientation" of a $3$-tuple of elements of $\mathbb{PF}_q^1$, as defined above?

**Example:** the positively oriented subsets in $\mathbb{PF}_5^1$ are:
$$\{0,1,\infty\},\{1,2,\infty\},\{2,3,\infty\},\{3,4,\infty\},\{0,4,\infty\},\{0,1,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{0,2,3\},\{1,3,4\},\{0,2,4\}$$

Comment: You could give little more context. How did this question arise?

Comment: It originally arose when I was trying to construct the isomorphism $\mathrm{PGL}_2(5)\to S_5$. The group $\mathrm{PGL}_2(5)$ acts on the $10$ partitions of $\mathbb{PF}_5^1$ into two three-element subsets. I was trying to construct a $5$-element set which is also acted on by $\mathrm{PGL}_2(5)$.

Comment: It sounds like you just gave a nice interpretation of orientation. Also I imagine there might be a construction involving the binary icosahedral group and $S^3\cong{\rm SU}(2)$ (then matrices mod $5$).